# Deadlocks in Sql Server 2008 but not 2005: concurrent SqlBulkCopy

Tags: sql-server, locking, deadlock, sqlbulkcopy, database-deadlocks

I am running concurrent bulk copies into a sql table that already holds data. 
There are a few indexes on the table but in this case no clustered indexes, just non-clustered. The table is not partitioned.

On a Sql Server 2005 platform I have no problems, the data is copied quickly and perfectly.
When I run the same process on Sql Server 2008, on this particular table I invariably experience a "PID x was deadlocked on lock resources with ... re-run the transaction."

In my efforts to solve this I have disabled page locking on the tables indexes and disabled lock escalation to no avail.

Any suggestions are much appreciated. 
I have researched this extensively but can't help feeling I am missing something. 
Deadlock graphs do not show anything other than lots of ellipses laid on top of each - in fact they look nothing like other deadlock graphs I have seen online.

Comment: Did you check whose PID you were deadlocking with?  I have a tendency to keep a table open in SSMS, thus causing my own deadlock for the insert.

Comment: Post the deadlock graph (the orginal XML, not the image)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Andomar. 
I assume my concurrent threads are deadlocking with each other on lock resources. Do you know how I could verify this? 
PIDs 65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73   < suggests the first 9 processes are locking against the 10th.

Comment: Looking closer at the deadlock graph in XML, I saw "SetCnstNotTrusted" which surprised me as I had disabled all FK constraints on the table. However I've found there is a lone default constraint remaining. Now running the process with this deleted and hoping that will be the end of my problems!